# Как обратиться к функции, не делая ее статичной?

Tags: функции, php, namespace, классы

Заранее извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос.

Я не нашел адекватной документации с более-менее развернутыми примерами и сам не смог разобраться.

**file1.php**

```
namespace myProject {

class myClass {

    private $myVariable = 'THIS IS WORK!';

    function myFunction() {

        return $this->myVariable;

    }
}
}
```

**file2.php**

```
include 'file1.php';
echo myProject\myClass::myFunction(); \\ Не работает, ибо это не статичный класс
echo myProject\myClass\myFunction(); \\ Не работает, PHP говорит, что не находит такой функции в данном файле.
```

Я опустил `<? ?>` здесь. Собственно, вопрос: как мне обратиться к функции, не делая ее статичной? Возможно вообще это?

Еще такой вопрос: как быть с `$this`, если я сделаю функцию статичной, то и переменную придется сделать статичной и обращаться к ней уже через `::`.

Главным все же является то, как обратиться к функции, не делая ее статичной.

Заранее огромное спасибо. Если можно еще, дайте нормальную документацию по namespace, могу и сам почитать :)

Comment: А может, ее сделать обычной функцией, а не методом?


    namespace myProject {

      function myFunction() {
        //....
        return $myVariable;

      }
  }

Comment: Нельзя вызвать нестатичный метод класса, не создавая объекта. Для передачи как callable надо передать массив из двух значений: первое - объект, второе - имя функции:

    call_user_func([new myClass, 'myFunction']);